# add bar button item next to back button on navigational bar

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have dragged+dropped Navigational bar from storyboard and a bar button item is placed at the left extreme .

I would like to add another button next to it but I am unable to do it ,its only excepting on the right extreme.I dont want that .

Its on iPad so there is lots of space on the navigational bar.How Do I implement this ?

I tried creating a bar button item but that covers the navigation bar and that not what I exactly want .

I want hide the 1 button of toolbar if possible so that back button of navigational bar can be seen .

Please suggest me something on how to get a Bar Button Item next Left extreme button on a Navigational Bar ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on using your own custom back button, and are willing to link the back action manually, (which I'm guessing you are because you added a nav bar in IB, not from the nav controller) you can use a [UIToolBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Tool bars support multiple buttons, and allow you to more precisely arrange them using fixed and flexible space UIBarButtonItems.

[image]

To do this to a navigation bar added by your navigation controller, you have to add the buttons programmatically:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];
UIBarButtonItem *myItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myItem1,myItem2, nil]];
```

Comment: What If I have a Navigational Controller then How DO I satisfy the above requirement.Any Ideas ?

Comment: @JacobWood See my edit, it's possible but you have to do it in code rather than interface builder.